# Powershell XML update file preserve formatting with line breaks

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing

I want to add notes to the cdata element of my xml but also preserve formatting with line breaks. I am able to add the info to cdata element but line breaks go away.

Current XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<info>
  <![CDATA[]>
</info>
```

Powershell Script:

```
$filePath = "info.xml"
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load($filePathToTask)
$element =  $xml.SelectSingleNode("//info")
$element.'#cdata-section' = '
      Notes go here with this format
      - Example
      - Example
      - Example'
$xml.Save($filePath)
```

Comment: Try to use [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1#here-strings).

Comment: ```$filePath = "info.xml"
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load($filePathToTask)
$element =  $xml.SelectSingleNode("//info")
$element.'#cdata-section' = @"
      Notes go here with this format
      - Example
      - Example
      - Example"@
$xml.Save($filePath)``` tried this.. no luck

Comment: Try to insert `$xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true` before `$xml.Save()`